# UE5 crashed when trying to assign actor references

Tags: unreal-engine5

So I have a couple of issues -

1. Whenever I turn off UE5 and turn it back on, many of my actors are unloaded. How do I fix this?
2. On the level sequencer, when I select Fix actor references, it crashed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0L8L.png)

Can someone shed some lights on these two issues please? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share code (as **text**, not as a screen shot) that reproduces the problem?  From [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem... if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some. But don't just copy in your entire program... Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, it's likely that you are using world partition. You need to load the cells of the area you are in to see everything.

Go to `Window->World Partition-> World Partition Editor`.

[image: World partition editor]

In the editor, you can see a mini version of the world. The white arrow thing is where you are in the world currently. Click and drag inside the mini map on the area that you want to load. The cells that you highlight will be grey.

[image: Selecting cells]

Then right click on the grey area and click load selected cells.